# Draw a graph in excel from C#

Tags: c#, excel, charts

I need to export some data I got from a device to an Excel sheet and plot a graph in it as well. I have been successful in exporting data to excel and when I open the excel sheet I'm getting correct data. So far so good. I have seven columns in total. I need to plot a graph with first column values on X axis (right) and 4,5,6 column values on Y axis(top). I'm using NetOffice for this (version is 1.7.3). So far I'm using the below code to draw graph

```
 Excel.Tools.CommonUtils utils = new Excel.Tools.CommonUtils(excelApplication);
            Excel.Workbook workBook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Add();
            Excel.Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Worksheets[1];
```

// then in a while loop

```
 workSheet.Cells[2, 2].Value = "Time";
                workSheet.Cells[2, 3].Value = "Moving Average Temperature";
                workSheet.Cells[2, 4].Value = "Temperature";
                workSheet.Cells[2, 5].Value = "Moving Average Temperature in °C";
                workSheet.Cells[2, 6].Value = "Temperature in °C";
                workSheet.Cells[2, 7].Value = "Base Temperature in °C";
                workSheet.Cells[2, 8].Value = "Table ID";
```

after a function where i receive data,,

```
workSheet.Cells[2 + Glory, 2].Value = time;
                        workSheet.Cells[2 + Glory, 3].Value = MAT;
                        workSheet.Cells[2 + Glory, 4].Value = T;
                        workSheet.Cells[2 + Glory, 5].Value = MATDC;
                        workSheet.Cells[2 + Glory, 6].Value = TIC;
                        workSheet.Cells[2 + Glory, 7].Value = BTC;
                        workSheet.Cells[2 + Glory, 8].Value = TID;
                        Glory++;
```

after finishing data collection,

```
string rangeGot = "$E5:$G"+Glory;
Excel.Range dataRange;
dataRange = workSheet.Range(rangeGot);
                    Excel.ChartObject chart = ((Excel.ChartObjects)workSheet.ChartObjects()).Add(70, 100, 375, 225);
                    chart.Chart.ChartType = Excel.Enums.XlChartType.xlLineStacked;
 chart.Chart.SetSourceData(dataRange);
 workBook.SaveAs(savedAddress);
Process.Start("excel.exe", savedAddress);
```

Here is where Im stuck. The data values are correct. But the graph I get looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/50gyp.png

The data I have is like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6fe4.png

I need to plot graphs with first column (time) on x axis and the rest on y axis. Can somebody please help me with this.

Another issue I'm facing is that the data is adding up. What I mean is all three lines should be intersecting with each other at least once since they are all in 24-25 range. But they are being plotted with a difference of ~25 each. Why is this happening and how can I avoid this. The help documents in NetOffice are almost none. It seems its very close to Microsoft excel interop dll (which I cant add for some lame reason). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would help to post the complete code

Comment: Im sorry I cant do that. The entire code spans over 16 classes and I dont see how I can put it here without the site blocking it. But what ever tests I'm doing with Netoffice, I created a separate project and did in it. If you want to run the code with test data I'll attach it. But its more about knowing function overloads and properties I think.